# I'm able to SSH into port 22 even though SSH service is running on random high port

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd

I have edited sshd_config. 22 is used by different process.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3393            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      293841/sshd: /usr/s     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      189130/python
```

Why am I still able to SSH using the following command? #ssh root@IP_address

I'm also able to login using the following command but this is expected: #ssh -p 3393 root@IP_address

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh redir ports 3393
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh redir ports 3393
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh redir ports 3393
```

And I also have executed the following command as root:

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/22
sudo chown new_user:new_user /etc/authbind/byport/22
sudo chmod 770 /etc/authbind/byport/22
```

Comment: What process is using port 22 and what does it do?

Comment: Those iptables PREROUTING rules seem to be to be rerouting your connect requests to port 3393 away from your ssh daemon to the python program running on 22. So the ssh service isn't even being accessed

Comment: It's a SSH honeypot 'cowrie'. If it was re-routing I shouldn't get a root access to login to the shell.